# Внешняя сортировка многопутевым двухфазным простым слиянием с внутренней сортировкой

Tags: алгоритм, файлы, сортировка

Дана задача реализовать алгоритм сортировки многопутевым двухфазным простым слиянием с внутренней сортировкой.

В чём суть многопутевого двухфазного простого слияния я уже понял:
Например, последовательность из чисел (файл с числами) f0: 2 9 15 1 55 43 100 66 99 22 7 12 10 5.
Используем 3 вспомогательных файла и разобьем исходную последовательность, получается:
f1: 2  1  100 22 10|
f2: 9  55 66  7  5 |
f3: 15 43 99  12|

Далее сливаем по числу из файла в упорядоченные тройки и записываем в исходный:
f0: 2 9 15 1 43 55 6 99 100 7 12 22 5 10

Далее процесс уже повторяется, только вместо чисел берутся тройки чисел и так, пока не получим одну упорядоченную серию.

Не очень понимаю, куда здесь подставлять внутреннюю сортировку. На первом шаге, который я описал, с ее помощью еще можно отсортировать поочередно все тройки чисел. Но как поступать дальше, когда вспомогательные файлы будут состоять не из чисел, а из троек чисел и т.д.?

Comment: *как поступать дальше, когда вспомогательные файлы будут состоять не из чисел, а из троек чисел* А в чём сложность-то? у тебя три сортированных потока, на каждом шаге ты просто берёшь минимальное из трёх чисел на вершине потока и сбрасываешь в выход, поток выносит наверх следующее число. И делаешь так, пока все три потока не опустеют.

Comment: как слить упорядоченные последовательности в одну, я понимаю. Каким образом при этом использовать внутреннюю сортировку?

Comment: Вероятно, имеется в виду, что нужно представить, что памяти достаточно, чтобы  в ней создать массив из элементов с вершин потоков, и внутренней сортировкой найти минимальный из них для перемещения его в выходной поток.